# A Quick Question about Subgroups of Dihedral Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm asked to show that $H = \{1, r^2, s, sr^2 \}$ is a subgroup of $D_8$, and I'm trying to use the Subgroup Criterion for Finite Groups; i.e., that $H$ is not empty, and $H$ is closed under multiplication.

However, unless I'm misunderstanding something, $H$ doesn't appear to be closed under multiplication (unless we allow for commutativity, which I assume we don't).

For example, take the elements $r^2$ and $s$. Well, $r^2 s \notin H$.

What is it I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: $r^2 s =s r^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r^2$ is in the center of $D_n$ (i.e it does commute with everything) so $r^2s = sr^2 \in H$.

Comment: Ok, yeah. I was rotating my square improperly. Thanks.

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude you're welcome !